# Как отследить блокировку бота пользователем? aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Возник такой вопрос. Можно ли отследить в aiogram, что человек заблокировал бота и если можно, то как?

Comment: При отправке сообщения во 2ой версии аиограма ловить исключение `BotBlocked`. В 3 - https://docs.aiogram.dev/uk-ua/latest/dispatcher/errors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Есть специальный апдейт - `my_chat_member`

Вот хендлер когда пользователь бота заблокировал:

```
@router.my_chat_member(ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(member_status_changed=KICKED))
async def user_blocked_bot(event: ChatMemberUpdated):
    pass # что-нибудь делаем, когда бота заблокировали
```

А это, когда бота разбанили:

```
@router.my_chat_member(ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(member_status_changed=MEMBER))
async def user_unblocked_bot(event: ChatMemberUpdated):
    pass # что-нибудь делаем, когда бота разблокировали
```